# cumulative function F is continuous at one point c, then there exist some interval(a,b) consists c and F is continuous in (a,b)

Tags: analysis, probability-theory

cumulative function F is continuous at one point c, then there exist some interval(a,b) consists c and F is continuous in (a,b)

I want to proof or disprove this statement, but I have no idea.
I think I should use that F is monotone and right continuous, but I have no clue.
Somebody help me!

Comment: I believe statement is false. Cumulative function can have countably many discontinuities, hence it can be dense.

Answer (score 2):

The statement in the title of your question is not true.

---

Counterexample:

Let $(q_n)_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb Q$ such that $\mathbb Q=\{q_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$.

Let $(p_n)_n$ be a sequence in $(0,\infty)$ such that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}p_n=1$.

Let $X$ be a random variable having distribution determined by $P(X=q_n)=p_n$.

Then for every $r\in\mathbb R-\mathbb Q$ the CDF of $X$ is continuous at $r$, but an interval $(a,b)$ with $r\in(a,b)$ where the CDF is continuous does not exist.

This because every element of $\mathbb Q$ is a discontinuity point of the CDF and $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.